# Angular: delegation pattern. The way to optimise handlers inside ngFor

Tags: javascript, angular

**For example:** I need to output a list. Each item will have a (click) handler with item object like parameter.

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of myList">
          <button (click)="clickHandler(item)"></button>       
    </li>
</ul>
```

This list will be updated dynamically quite often: I will load new items onScroll, or filter the list by search.

For each item Angular adds an event listener!

**Question:**

It can be a lot of items in the list, so a lot of eventListeners will be connected and disconnected all the time.

**Is there a way to apply delegation pattern to have only one eventListener live?**

Comment: This is common practice. Nothing to worry about. Can you come up with an alternative if you want to compare it performance-wise ;) ?

Comment: @lexith Add handler to parent element `<ul>`. Set attribute for each item data-itemId.

Comment: @lexith `clickHandler(event) {
  if (!event.target.dataset.itemId) {
     return;
  }
  const item = this.getItemById()
}`

Comment: @Smiranin You just stated the answer to your own question; put the click handler on the `ul` element: `<ul (click)="clickHandler($event)"><li *ngFor="let item of myList"><button></button></li></ul>`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `trackBy` to improve perforamnce.

### app.component.html

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of myList; trackBy: trackByFn">
          <button (click)="clickHandler(item)"></button>       
    </li>
</ul>
```

### app.component.ts

```
trackByFn(index, item) {
    return index; // or item.id
}
```

Angular can track which items have been added or removed according to the unique identifier and create or destroy only the items that changed when you change your collection.

You also can dive into `Event delegation` in `JS`.

[Event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation)

Answer (score 0):

You have nothing to worry about here. The new Angular change detection will take care of performance for you, and there shouldn't be an active listener on every item. It's a common pattern, and should not affect performance.

Comment: I hope) As I know, angular-4 has bugs with change detections. Sometimes it does not work. I hope in angular-5 will fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about the individual items and instead use virtual scrolling from the CDK module to make it possible to show millions of items (at least in Chrome, Firefox has a stricter max height for the parent container). Sidenote: always use trackBy in ngFor, even if it just a truckByIndex (less flickering of re-used components).